# During a render, why wrap a functional component in a React.createElement instead of utlizing its returned element via a function call?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-dom

```js
const App = () => {
 return React.createElement(
   "div",
   {},
   React.createElement('h1', {}, "Adopt The Pet"))
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(App(), document.getElementById("root")); // this works

// vs

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById("root"));
```

I am following an introduction to react course in which the author uses the **second** version with a new `React.createElement()` wrapper. I can't figure out the need to do so even after going through the relevant react docs.

The first version already returns a `React.createElement()` so why not *use **that** returned element* instead of wrapping it inside a **new** `React.createElement()`?

**Edit:** Even the React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component) uses the course author's method if you translate the doc's JSX to `React.createElement()` calls but again, they haven't explained why.

```js
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

// React.createElement(Welcome, {name : Sara})
const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />; 

// Why not just do this?
const element =  Welcome({Sara})

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What happens if you pass in `App` without the surrounding `React.createElement`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox do you mean App() or App?

Comment: Sorry I see now that you did try that. It's likely that the course author felt it was safer to wrap `App` in a react element, but we can't say for sure. Why not ask them?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't think I can contact the author :/.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with what a "React component" actually is. According to the React documentation:

> Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen. - https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Boiling that down I understand a React component to be "a function that returns a React element" (ignoring classes altogether for now).

```js
function component() {
  return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')
}
```

So if that's the case, we should be able to pass our React component directly to `ReactDOM.render()` or `React.createElement()`:

```js
ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById("root"))
// or
React.createElement('div', null, component)
```

But we can't. This doesn't work. It gives us the following error:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Sure, we can fix this by invoking our function:

```js
ReactDOM.render(component(), document.getElementById("root"))
// or
React.createElement('div', null, component())
```

But is that really a React component? No. It's just invoking a plain old function to ultimately get a React element as the return value. To illustrate this point further, look what happens when we try and use the `useState` hook:

```js
function component() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
  return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')
}

ReactDOM.render(component(), document.getElementById("root"))
```

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

But wait a minute, we thought we had a function React component?

A function that returns a React element does not become a "React component" until it is passed as the first argument to `React.createElement()`.

This makes sense if we think about it. If you define a function, there's no way for React to know that your function is a React component. You pass the function as reference, but React doesn't know that what you're passing will ultimately return a React element (per our definition). We need to somehow indicate to React that our function is indeed a "React component." We do this by passing. our function as the first argument to `React.createElement()`

```js
// Regular old function
function component() {
  return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')
}

// becomes a React component
React.createElement(component)
```

This, among other things like the `useState()` hook above, is also required for React to take control of the props passed as arguments to our function, so it can re-render when our props change. We have to give React control of our function. So, to amend our previous definition of what a React element is, we land here:

A React component is "a function that returns a React element and is passed as the first argument to React.createElement()"

When we use JSX this is all abstracted away, so I assume that why people don't really talk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Galupuf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70279264/2477619) below and the limitation of not being able to use hooks when directly calling functional components, [React's "Design Principles"](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html) provide a clear explanation of why it is discouraged to call functional components manually.

> **Even when your components are described as functions, when you use
> React you don’t call them directly.** Every component returns a
> description of what needs to be rendered, and that description may
> include both user-written components like  and
> platform-specific components like . **It is up to React to “unroll”
>  at some point in the future and actually apply changes to
> the UI tree according to the render results of the components
> recursively.**
>
> This is a subtle distinction but a powerful one. Since you don’t call
> that component function but let React call it, it means React has the
> power to delay calling it if necessary.